# If/Else if/Else Ternary

Tags: css, reactjs, conditional-statements, conditional-operator, ternary

I am trying to do some coniditonal styling in react js. Very new to react, so there may be a better way to do this, but have searched the internet to no avail. I am trying to check the screen size and style based off of said screen size. In this use case I am wanting to center some text based off of screen size. Can someone please tell me if there is a better way to do this? This is not working for me currently.

Edit: Placed some logs in there and what it is doing exactly is when the page loads "textAlign" is not applied to the element at all even though the screen size is > 993px. Once I shrink the screen down to < 993px and > 578px is applies the "textAlign: center" to the element and then once it shrinks down < 578px it does not set it back to none. It keeps it centered.

```
const styles = {
    footerColOne:{
        textAlign: deviceSize > 993 ? "none" : (deviceSize < 993 && deviceSize > 578) ? "center" : "none",
        paddingLeft: deviceSize < 993 ? "26px" : "80px",
        paddingTop: deviceSize < 993 ? "28px" : "63px",
    },
    footerColTwo:{
        textAlign: deviceSize > 993 ? "none" : (deviceSize < 993 && deviceSize > 578) ? "center" : "none",
        paddingLeft: deviceSize < 993 ? "26px" : deviceSize < 578 ? "51px" : "50px",
        paddingTop: deviceSize < 993 ? "40px" : "86px",
    },
  }
```

I am then calling that style like this

```
<Col lg={3} style={ styles.footerColOne }>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Last Edit:**

So I have found media queries is indeed the preferred way to go here, my ternary condition above worked though I made an idiot mistake and was setting `textAlign` to `none` when that value does not exist for that property. It should be set to `initial` in this case.

Comment: You should be using media query instead of doing programmatically. [Media Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Normally I would hand these using media query with sass, it's much easier.

Comment: "This is not working for me currently." in what way is it not working? Where is `deviceSize` generated and have you logged it to console to check it's present and corrent?

Comment: @DavePritlove It is not working in the way that is does not seem to be taking the middle condition. Logging it returns the proper screen size, etc. I have generated the screen size with a function above. Did not post it.

Comment: @DavePritlove Typed up exactly what happens in the edit above.

Comment: ` deviceSize > 993 ? "none" : (deviceSize < 993 && deviceSize > 578) ? "center" : "none"` simplifies to `deviceSize > 993 ? "none" : deviceSize > 578 ? "center" : "none"` As the second condition is never reached unless deviceSize is <993. (you should probably use <= in the first test for when deviceSize==993). Not sure that will make a difference but it's best to keep nested ternaries as simple as possible

Comment: Agree with other comments that this method is less ideal, but the expression for `textAlign` can be just `deviceSize > 578 && deviceSize < 993 : "center" : "none"` because it seems `"center"` is only needed when the "middle" condition is met. It seems this could be the reason for the issue. That being said, I do recommend to use media query like all the comments mentioned.

Comment: Another thought, is the function that supplies `deviceSize` and the `styles` object, inside an event listener? I don't think assigning an expression to an object property would cause it to update when a variable inside the expression changes. Perhaps the style object could be declared global, will all its property keys and default values and then set each one as assignments in an event listener e.g. `styles.footerColOne.textAlign = deviceSize > 578 && deviceSize < 993 : "center" : "none"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`media query` will be good fit here.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 578px) and (max-width: 993px) {
  .someclass {
   text-align:center;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 993px) {
  .someclass {
   text-align:center;
   padding-left:26px;
   padding-right:28px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 993px) {
  .someclass {
    text-align:left /* none as you wanted. /*;
  }
}
```

So given,

`max-width` all the styles inside this `media query` will be applied if screen size is below this `max-width`.

`min-width` all the styles inside this `media query` will be applied if the screen size is greater than the `min-width`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const getDevice = (deviceSize) => 
    deviceSize < 993 
        ? (deviceSize < 993 && deviceSize > 578) 
            ? 'tablet'
            : 'mobile'
        : 'web'


// if declare css -> return class
// component use className instead of styles
// <Col lg={3} className={...} />
const footerColOne = {
    'web': () => {

        return {
            textAlign: 'none',
            paddingLeft: '26px',
            paddingTop: '28px'
        }
    },
    'tablet': () => {
        return {
            textAlign: 'center',
            paddingLeft: '80px',
            paddingTop: '63px'
        }
    },
    'mobile': () => {
        return {
            textAlign: 'none',
            paddingLeft: '80px',
            paddingTop: '63px'
        }
    }
}


const styles = {
    footerColOne: footerColOne[getDevice(deviceSize)]()
}

console.log(styles.footerColOne)

// <Col lg={3} style={ styles.footerColOne }>
```

Comment: you can use className instead of a return object.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have never seen it this way before. How would you then call that  in the element "<Col lg={3} style={ styles.footerColOne }>" to apply styling?

Comment: Ok. You are saying I can set footerColOne as className?

Comment: This is great. I log it and everything looks good, but a little unsure on how to apply this so it takes the styling

Comment: Thank you - I have applied the above. It is doing pretty much the same thing as was happening prior. When I shrink screen down tablet it centers it, but when it hits mobile it never takes it off center. Keeps it centered. Any ideas?

Comment: @programmerGuy I don't think it'll be possible to judge by the code above. You need to check for complex applications such as CSS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).